# Harmonic functions on $\{1<|z|<2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find all complex-valued harmonic functions on $\{1<|z|<2\}$ that extend continuously to $\{|z|=2\}$ and take value $0$ on that circle.

My first idea was to map $\{1<|z|<2\}$ to a subset of $\mathbb{H}$ (the upper half plane) and use Schwarz reflection principle. But this doesn't seem to work. So now I'm stuck...

Comment: I don't see in what sense you're going to "find" them all. That annulus is a Dirichlet domain, so for example there's going to be one for each continuous function on $|z|=1$. What does the problem ask, exactly? (For example one could "find" all the _radial_ harmonic functions that vanish on $|z|=2$...)

Comment: The problem asks exactly what I asked. But what do you mean by there's one for each function on $|z|=1$. Is this correspondance bijective. If yes, that may be the answer...

Comment: The problem does not say "I have to find...". The reason I'm curious about the exact wording is I really can't see exactly what it means to "find" them all. Yes, _if_ we restrict to functions continuous on the closure of the annulus those are in a natural bijection with continuous functions on $|z|=1$, but saying that doesn't seem to me like "finding" them. Hmm. Any harmonic function in that annulus is $c log|z| + f + \overline g$, where $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic; that gives you a Fourier-series representation (with the constraint that all the coefficients of $e^{int}$ vanish for $|z|=2$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some functions that are harmonic in $1 < |z| < 2$ and vanish at $|z|=2$:
$$
                (z/2)^{n}-(2/\overline{z})^{n},(\overline{z}/2)^{n}-(2/z)^{n},\ln(|z|/2).
$$
In polar form, these are
$$
                  ((r/2)^{n}-(2/r)^{n})e^{in\theta},((r/2)^{n}-(2/r)^{n})e^{-in\theta},\ln(r/2).
$$
There are enough of these to expand the function at $r=1$ in a Fourier series:
$$
                    h(r,\theta)=c_0\ln(r/2)+\sum_{n=-\infty,n\ne 0}^{\infty}((r/2)^{n}-(2/r)^{n})c_ne^{in\theta} \\
            h(1,\theta)=c_0\ln(1/2)+\sum_{n\ne 0}(2^{-n}-2^{n})c_ne^{in\theta}
$$
The coefficient $c_0$ is determined as a Fourier coefficient:
$$
           -c_0\ln 2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}h(1,\theta)d\theta.
$$
For $n\ne 0$,
$$
           c_n(2^{-n}-2^{n})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}h(1,\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta
$$
This gives you an explicit representation of $h(r,\theta)$ in terms of Fourier coefficient integrals of the given boundary function $f(\theta)=h(1,\theta)$.